# Недоступные элементы в контекстном меню

Tags: activity, android, java, popupmenu

Здравствуйте!

У меня такой вопрос. У меня есть ListView и для каждого элемента этого listview можно вызвать свое контекстное меню. Но в некоторых случаях некоторые элементы этого меню должны быть недоступны для выбора.

Я слышал, что это делается в методе `onPrepareOptionsMenu` активити. Но проблема в том, что мое контекстное меню не одно на всю активити, а должно быть разным для каждого элемента ListView. То есть определить эту логику в `onPrepareOptionsMenu` не представляется возможным - я не смогу обрабатывать каждое контекстное меню для каждого элемента Listview.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18632538/1360579